# Swagger auto generation doesn't include error classes

Tags: swift, swagger

My swagger definition defines responses like:

```
responses:
    '200':
      description: ''
      schema:
        type: object
        properties:
          response:
            type: array
            items:
              $ref: '#/definitions/InstalledAccount'
    '404':
      description: ''
      schema:
        type: object
        properties:
          errors:
            type: array
            items:
              $ref: '#/definitions/Error'
```

When I auto generate the swift classes I get a method like:

```
public class func getAccountLocation(DEV_REF DEV_REF: String, ACCOUNT_CODE: String, completion: ((data: InlineResponse200?, error: ErrorType?) -> Void))
```

When a 404 is encountered, both data and error are both nil - it doesn't appear to take into account the different schema for 404.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I know, swagger-codegen generates very simple code stubs for most (or all) languages. Generated clients doesn't implement full specification now. Generated servers just simple routes mocks.

I thing your question doesn't look like a problem, but looks like a issue for swagger-codegen.

https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues

Answer (score 2):

this extension worked for me

```
import "your generated swagger framework"

extension Error {

    var code: Int {
        guard let err = self as? ErrorResponse
            else { return (self as NSError).code }

        switch err{
        case ErrorResponse.error(let code, _, _):
            return code
        }
    }
}
```